# How to find variance of multivariable expression

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, variance, bootstrap

I have an expression of this form
$W_i = a * X_i * (1 - Y_i * (1 - Z_i))$,

where $a$ is a constant, $X_i \sim Bernoulli({p_x}_i)$,

$Y_i \sim Bernoulli({p_y}_i)$, and

$Z_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma)$

**Background**:
So, I have three models for X, Y and Z, and these are models for probability of survival, probability of death, and a model for some distance measure, respectively. So X and Y are logistic regression models, and Z is a normal regression model. I have a dataset, and I predict the expected values for the three models, and then I calculate `W`. But I know that this expected `W` has a high degree of uncertainty attached to it, because the underlying drivers are highly uncertain. I wish to get a distribution of W for all datapoints, so I can measure the uncertainty.

**Attempt**:
I have 100k rows of data, so $i = {1,2,3,...,100000}$, where I have predicted values in each row for ${p_x}_i$, ${p_y}_i$ and $\mu_i$, and $\sigma$ is constant/equal for all rows. I want to find the variance of the expression for `W` above for each row, and I've tried Monte Carlo sampling, and then bootstrapping to find the variance, but it is just very slow.

Is there a faster way to do this, or do I need to calculate $Var(W_i)$ "by hand"?

**Code**:

```
# data
set.seed(1234)
n <- 100000
p_x <- rnorm(n, 0.3, 0.02)
p_y <- rnorm(n, 0.7, 0.02)
mu_z <- rnorm(n, 0.5, 0.05)
sigma = 0.1
a = 10

# monte carlo simulations
## duplicate each i/observation n_mc times using rep(), and sample
n_mc = 100
X <- rbinom(n * n_mc, 1, rep(p_x, each = n_mc))
Y <- rbinom(n * n_mc, 1, rep(p_y, each = n_mc))
Z <- rnorm(n * n_mc, rep(mu_z, each = n_mc), sd = rep(sigma, n * n_mc))
W <- X * (1 - (Y * (1 - Z))) * a
W <- matrix(W, nrow=n, ncol=n_mc, byrow=TRUE)

# bootstrap
## since each row in W is a sample, we bootstrap this sample to obtain variance/or confidence intervals
library(boot)
getMean <- function(x, ind){
  mean(x[ind], na.rm = TRUE)
}
out <- do.call(rbind, apply(W, 1, FUN = function(x) 
      {
    x1 <- boot.ci(boot(x, statistic = getMean, R = 1000), conf = 0.8, type="perc")
    data.frame(mean = x1$t0, lowerCI = x1$percent[4], upperCI = x1$percent[5])
      }))
```

Comment: Ok, I just realized that since all variables are independent, I can just use $Var(W) = E(W^2) - E(W)^2$, and calculate the direct expression! It is a long calculation though, so if anybody has another solution, maybe in `R`, that would be nice :)

Comment: This is not a long calculation. Just use the rules for the variance: $Var(aX) = a^2Var(X)$ and (for independent $X,Y$) $Var(XY)=Var(X)Var(Y) + Var(X) E(Y)^2 + Var(Y)E(X)^2$. And for a binomial variable, the variance is $np(1-p)$. Writing this down should not last longer than 15 minutes.

Comment: How do you obtain values for probabilities and distribution parameters?  These, by their very definition, are not observable and cannot be observed: they are hypothetical constructs whose values can only be estimated.

Comment: @cdalitz can't I do it like I did it? Yes, it took me 5 minutes, but that I considered long :)

Comment: @whuber you mean my "data". These were predictions from models.

Comment: @berthrand-eros "it took me 5 minutes, but that I considered long"  I am amazed that coding a bootstrap method was faster for you. You must be a fats coder ;-)

Comment: Because they are predictions, they have some uncertainty attached to them.  So where you ask to compute the variance, please note that your answer will not incorporate that component of uncertainty.  In effect it is a *conditional* variance.  Note, too, that some simplification is possible.  For instance, $1-Z$ has a Normal$(1-\mu,\sigma)$ distribution; the factor of $a$ merely contributes a multiplicative factor of $a^2$ to the variance; and so on.  But before we think about this, it would be nice to know whether your calculation even is meaningful.

Comment: @cdalitz you are right, it took me longer, I started off badly :) But thanks for the advice, I'll calculate it in a little bit :)

Comment: @whuber ah, great point, thank you! I overlooked that it would be a conditional variance. But it will be hard to take that into account, right? I have three regression models that calculate expectations for X, Y and Z, so I just figured that W would be highly uncertain, and I would like to get some glimplse of that uncertainty. I just assumed that would be meaningful, but it is highly probable I'm overlooking something you are seeing here :)

Comment: Sometimes we can solve hard problems ;-).  It would be nice to know what your application really is, because we prefer to help you solve your underlying problem rather than settling for mathematical answers to questions that might turn out to be irrelevant or less than helpful.

Comment: @whuber You are too kind! So, I have three models for X, Y and Z, like I said, and these are models for probability of survival, probability of death, and a model for some distance measure, respectively. So X and Y are logistic regression models, and Z is a normal regression model. I have a dataset, and I predict the expected values for the three models, and then I calculate W. But I know that this expected W has a high degree of uncertainty attached to it, because the underlying drivers are highly uncertain, like you point out. I wish to get a distribution of W for all datapoints, in the end.

Comment: Thank you -- but in order for that information to be read and appreciated by most readers, it's important to include it in an edit to your post.

Comment: @whuber Of course, thank you, I'll include it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer and partially a request for clarification.

If I understand correctly,

- $a$ is a constant.
- $X_i$ is Bernoulli with $\Pr(X_i=1)=p_i.$
- $Y_i$ is Bernoulli with $\Pr(Y_i=1)=q_i.$  (I changed the names of the parameters slightly to avoid cascading subscripts.)
- $Z_i$ has a Normal$(\mu_i,\sigma)$ distribution.
- ***All the variables are independent.***  (If not, we don't have enough information to solve this problem.)

**To evaluate the distribution of $W_i=a X_i(1 - Y_i(1-Z_i)),$** ignore $a$ for the moment because all it does is scale everything and set $U_i = X_i(1 - Y_i(1-Z_i)).$  We will apply definitions and basic properties, beginning by noting that $(X_i,Y_i)$ is certain to be one of just four values, as presented in this table.

$$\begin{array}{rrlll}
& \Pr & X_i & Y_i & U_i\\ \hline
& (1-p_i)(1-q_i) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
& (1-p_i)q_i & 0 & 1 & 0\\
& p_i(1-q_i) & 1 & 0 & 1\\
& p_iq_i & 1 & 1 & Z_i\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

This evidently is a *mixture* of an atom at $0$ with probability $(1-p_i)(1-q_i)+(1-p_i)q_i = q_i,$ an atom at $1$ with probability $p_i(1-q_i),$ and a Normal variable $V_i.$  The calculation of its moments is immediate, so that in particular

$$E[U_i] = q_i(0) + p_i(1-q_i)(1) + p_iq_iE[Z_i] = p_i(1-q_i) + p_iq_i\mu_i$$

and, because $E[Z_i^2] = \operatorname{Var}(Z_i) + E[Z_i]^2 = \sigma^2 + \mu^2,$

$$E[U_i^2] = \cdots = p_i(1-q_i) + p_iq_i\left(\sigma^2 + \mu^2\right).$$

You can use the equation

$$\operatorname{Var}(W_i) = \operatorname{Var}(aU_i) = a^2 \operatorname{Var}(U_i) = a^2\left(E[U_i^2] - E[U_i]^2\right).$$

**At this point it's unclear what you want,** because in your code the parameters are themselves random variables.  Are you looking for the *unconditional* means and variances or, perhaps, for the variances *conditional* on any specific realization of these parameters, or (based on your bootstrap code) the conditional variance of the *mean* of the $W_i$?  In any case, you can easily continue this calculation by employing basic properties of expectations and variance.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is not known to me this about atoms, but I'll find some information on that!
Yes, I was looking for the conditional variance of the *mean* of **W**, like in my bootstrap code. To be honest, I'm not sure how to conceptualize your two first/other options as to what I'm looking for: "the *unconditional* means and variances", or "variances *conditional* on any specific realization of these parameters". I think you are on a different level of understanding the world than I am :)